# upload avi php errors

Tags: php, upload, avi

i get the following errors

```
     ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\wamp\www\upload_file.php on line 18 Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0003  377944  {main}( )   ..\upload_file.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\wamp\www\upload_file.php on line 24 Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0003  377944  {main}( )   ..\upload_file.php:0 Upload:

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\wamp\www\upload_file.php on line 25 Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0003  377944  {main}( )   ..\upload_file.php:0 Type:

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\wamp\www\upload_file.php on line 26 Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0003  377944  {main}( )   ..\upload_file.php:0 Size: 0 Kb

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\wamp\www\upload_file.php on line 27 Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0003  377944  {main}( )   ..\upload_file.php:0 Temp file:

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\wamp\www\upload_file.php on line 29 Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0003  377944  {main}( )   ..\upload_file.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\wamp\www\upload_file.php on line 31 Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0003  377944  {main}( )   ..\upload_file.php:0 already exists.
```

now the file that handles the fileupload 
is the following

```
?php session_start();

ini_set('memory_limit', "400M");
ini_set('max_execution_time', "900");
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', "400M");
ini_set('post_max_size', "400M");



$user=$_SESSION['MM_Username'];

$path="video". "\\" . $user . "\\";

if(!(is_dir($path))){
mkdir(dirname(__FILE__) . "\\". $path,0777);
}

  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists($path . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      $path. $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored !";
      }
    }

?>
```

if i try to upload a picture everything is fine , but when i try to upload a 300MB movieclip it gives the errors i posted above , i've changed the php.ini file on my wamp server that it allows bigger files to upload but still no result
anyone got an idea of whats going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the enctype attribute on your form.

Answer (score 0):

Another issue in your code is you don't even check if 'file' index exists in $_FILES[] array.
If it does not, you should report this as error instead of trying to use its contents.
This is better approach overall: check if every field you expect from a form to be there before even trying to use it.